# Will the armour piece where I put Protection affect its effects?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

If I put Protection on a Chestplate (for example) will it have a greater effect than on Boots?
**Will Protection be more effective on some armour pieces than anothers?**

Comment: Very nice question, I'm testing it now.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

#### No.

While the mechanics of enchanted armor are different in 1.8 and 1.9, the [protection enchantments](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Armor#Enchantments) reduce damage equally, no matter on which armor piece they are placed. There is a formula on the wiki to calculate the extra protection from enchantments ([in 1.9](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Armor#Upcoming_changes)):

> The EPFs of all applicable enchantments are added together and capped at 20. The damage is reduced as `damage = damage * ( 1 - cappedEPF / 25 )`, giving a maximum reduction of 80% at EPF 20.

Only the *total* (capped) EPF (Enchantment Protection Factor) is used for the calculation, and EPF calculation is the same no matter what armor piece you are looking at. This is true for both 1.8 and 1.9.

I also ran some tests in the 1.9 pre-release right now. I created a 3x4x3 obsidian box with water at the bottom (to prevent burning), and a single block window at one side as well as the top open. The window was used to trigger a set of command blocks to teleport me into the center of the box and summon a Fireball with Explosion power 3 above myself, heading downwards:

```
/tp @a 59 57 1
/summon Fireball 59 70 1 {direction:[0.0,-1.0,0.0],ExplosionPower:3}
```

I put on a diamond helmet, boots, and chestplate, one of which was enchanted with Protection IV. The fireball consistently did 4 Hearts of damage, regardless of which armor item was enchanted. Without any enchantments, the damage was 5 Hearts.

Comment: Please note that damage mitigation formulas will change in couple of weeks with the release of Minecraft 1.9. Also, please indicate which version your answer is about.

Comment: @OrcJMR I ran the tests in the 1.9 prerelease, but the formula from the wiki might be outdated, which might explain why there was no randomness to the damage. I will look into it some more.

Comment: In 1.9 snapshots, full armour damage absorption was reduced from 80% to 66%.

Answer (score 6):

I conducted an experiment to test your question(In 1.8.9) and the answer was NO.
First I tested each piece of leather armor without any effects:   **Boots:**[image]
**Chestplate:[image]**
**Helmet:**
[image]
**Leggings:**

[image]

Each test with normal leather armor ended with the same amount of damage taken. I had jumped from a height of 11 blocks and tested each armor piece one at a time with leather so the damage would be more significant and easier to read. You could probably draw the conclusion from this, but I decided to test just to make sure.  I gave myself Protection 2 leather armor and repeated the test. 
I used a command like this:

```
/give @p leather_helmet 1 0 {display: {Name: "hat"},ench: [{id: 0,lvl: 2}]}
```

[image]

Although the damage was decreased by half a heart the damage taken with each one on stayed the same.  As a last and final test I gave myself Protection 4 armor and jumped from a height of 15 blocks to make sure that my data didn't change.  [image][image]
...As I had expected the data didn't change and the damage taken was equal even on different pieces of armor.  I received a damage of five hearts on each of the last jumps with the different individual armor pieces.

This test should prove that enchantments don't change the defense value depending on the armor piece within one set.

Comment: What was your experiment? How much damage did you subject yourself to? Why did you test with leather armor, that reduces damage only slightly - are you sure you didn't overlook anything due to rounding?

Comment: Thanks for the questions, I edited my post to try and answer all those questions.

Comment: Wow, Pink Leather Armour.

Comment: Unenchanted armour doesn't reduce fall damage, you know.